# Dissection and explanation of (const char*) cast C in this string comparison function

Tags: c, casting

Through trial and error I managed to get the following string comparison function to work with qsort() as I intended but I don't really understand why the asterisk is needed in the (const char*) cast expression. Can someone please dissect and explain:-

```
int strCompare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp((const char*)a, (const char*)b);
}
```

Appendix:-

```
void findStrings(int * optionStats, char strings[][MAX_STRING_SIZE + 1], int numStrings)
{
    qsort(strings, numStrings, 21*sizeof(char), strCompare);
}
```

Is there a way of eliminating the call to strcmp() through strCompare() and just using strcmp() as the parameter to qsort() instead?

Comment: I trust that `MAX_STRING_SIZE + 1 == 21` as otherwise, you are fibbing to your compiler and compilers are apt to get their own back when you lie to them.  You'd probably be better off using the same notation for the value consistently.

Comment: Note that if you are sorting an array of pointers to char, you need a different string comparison routine: `int cmpStrings(const void *a, const void *b) { char *a1 = *(char **)a; char *b1 = *(char **)b; return strcmp(a1, b1); }`.

Comment: Yes MAX_STRING_SIZE + 1 == 21 and will replace 21 after debugging. The  function does seem to sort correctly but I will try your variation out of curiosity.

Comment: Don't try my code on your data; it is for a different job!  Related, but different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an asterisk because you want to convert a *pointer* to `const void` to a *pointer* to `const char` and an asterisk designates that they are pointer types.

In fact you don't really need conversion, since `pointer to void` type can be implicitly converted to `pointer to T` type in C language, which isn't the case for C++.

Comment: There were some good explanations but this seems to answer the original question well.

Answer (score 2):

As it's been mentioned by others here, you don't need to define a new function, just to cast the *pointer* types. Here's how you can cast *the function* while passing it to `qsort`, preventing any warning/error:

```
qsort(arr,
      sizeof(arr)/sizeof(char*),
      sizeof(char*),
      (int(*)(const void *, const void *))strcmp);
```

Comment: Ok now I understand why i don't need to wrap it in strcmp() in a seperate function. I'll mark this answer up. Thankyou

Comment: Strictly speaking, function pointer casts aren't well-defined behavior. In practice, they will almost always work as long as the calling convention and the size of the parameters are the same.

Comment: @Lundin, of course! The whole point behind the casting is, though, **telling the compiler that you know what you are doing.**

Comment: @behnam Not really. Many programmers cast because they don't know what they are doing and they want the compiler warnings to go away.

Comment: @behnam By the way, your code will only sort an array of pointers ("soft copy"), not an array of strings ("hard copy") which seems to be the OP's case.

Comment: Right, but that's not a *design pattern*, right? The freedom users have in C may lead mistakes easily, and it's up to the user to know how to use that freedom. IMO defining a function instead of casting is just unnecessary.

Comment: This code is just a demonstration on how to cast the function. I'm sure he knows how to set the other parameters for the `qsort` function. If you like to make it look like the sample in the OP's code, please feel free to edit the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `strcmp` is (there's another one, but this is the one you are using):

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

so, as the parameters of your function (`a` and `b`) are `const void`, you have to perform those casts.

This will be correct as long as the variables you are using as parameters when calling `qsort` will be passed to `strCompare` as `char *`.

Comment: That's what i thought but the compiler complains with warning: passing argument 4 of ‘qsort’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Comment: You are right, that's the reason. I will edit my answer removing my last question.

Comment: @nhahtdh That was the first thing I did but I got warning: passing argument 4 of ‘qsort’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]. Is there somethins I'm missing?

Comment: As an appendix you could add to your question the code in your project where you call `strCompare`, and what its parameters are.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I added the appendix.

Comment: @nhahtdh No you cannot. You would have to cast the function pointer type for that to work, and such casts are strictly speaking not well-defined behavior.

Comment: I have removed the wrong comment about passing `strcmp` directly to `qsort` function - didn't check before posting and I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
int strcmp(
   const char *string1,
   const char *string2 
);
```

is defined like that. If you do not cast it as " const char* ", the variable " a " is supposed to be of type pointer to void. Its better to understand if you type

`const void *a as const void* a`

> the asterisk is associated with the data-type.

So to cast the whole variable "a" as a pointer to a data-type of " const char ", you have to use asterisk too.